# how to switch language with playframework by browser language

Tags: playframework-2.2

I have added the messages and messages.fr files under conf folder, and need the code to switch the languages according to the language settings of the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need the code ;>

All you need is to add the French (`fr`) to your `application.conf`

```
application.langs="en,fr"
```

BTW, it's clearly described in official docs: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaI18N (even French is mentioned ;))

Comment: If i add messages.en-US and application.langs="en-US", then it works fine. But if i add messages.fr and application.langs="fr", the text will not load. It seems it only works with en, en-US

Comment: It works fine with all languages, open some inspector in your browser and check if request contains `Accept-Language` header and if it has `fr` on list